# Voltage shift via op amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, voltage-divider, level-shifting

I can't figure out a valid circuit for the following conditions:
I have an input signal varying from 0 V to 3 V. My ADC's voltage reference is 2.048 V. I only care about the input voltage starting from 0.768 V and ending at 2.048 V + 0.768 V.

So 0.768 V at the input (and bellow, since I have no negative voltages in the circuit) gives 0 V at the output.
2.816 V at the input (or higher) gives 2.048 V at the output.

So in practice, I just need to somehow offset the output signal by 0.768 V down (VOUT = VIN - 0.768 V assuming 0V is the minimum value).

[image]

I tried to set this up with a non-inverting level shifter circuit, but with no luck- is it the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Can you use two op amps? If so, I have an idea of how to implement this.

Comment: Yes, It doesn't have to be one op amp. I tried with 2 (second one used as non inverting amplifier behind the first one) but also failed.

Comment: OK. give me 10 minutes or so.

Comment: This TI app note walks you through design efforts like this very simply: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Sorry, taking longer than I thought.

Comment: No problem, I was not able to do this for a long time already... I appreciate your help. Also, thank you for the link Mark- will try to follow it.

Comment: @MarkOmo Interestingly enough, after I completed my design, I went to look at the TI app note. They divide the situation by cases. In this case m is positive, and b is negative. I then go to that case and they immediately ask me to divide by m-1. Hmm. m in this case is 1, so divide by 1-1? Further, they tell us that the circuit they give is not accurate, and offer a more accurate 2 op amp circuit. I would think m=1 would be a pretty common case and they would do better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be very simple, and you only need one op-amp and four resistors. Given the values I've shown, assuming ideal components the solution is exact. As a hint on how to get to this solution, attempt to solve for two cases: the first for when the output is zero, and the second for when the output is equal to Vref.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzPaH0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To get here:

If \$ V_{out} = 0 \$ , \$ R_3 \$ and \$ R_4 \$ form a voltage divider, \$ R_1 \$ and \$ R_2 \$ form a voltage divider, and \$ V_{in} = V_{off} \$ :

$$ V_n = \frac {V_{ref} R_4} {R_4 + R_3} $$
$$ V_p = \frac { V_{off} R_2 } {R_2 + R_1 } $$
$$ V_n = V_p \text{, so}$$
$$ \text{I. } 
V_{ref} R_4 \left(R_2 + R_1 \right) = V_{off} R_2 \left(R_4 + R_3\right)
$$

If \$ V_{out} = V_{ref} \$, there is no current through \$ V_n \$ so

$$ V_{out} = V_{ref} = V_{p} = V{n} $$

$$ \text{II. }
V_{ref} \left(R_2 + R_1 \right) =  \left(V_{ref} + V_{off} \right)
R_2  $$

Assign \$ R_1 / R_2 = a \$, \$ R_3 / R_4 = b \$ and you will find that \$ \text{I} \$ and \$ \text{II} \$ form a system of two equations, two unknowns. After a little algebra you will end up with

$$
\frac {R_1} {R_2} = \frac {R_4} {R_3} = \frac {V_{off}} {V_{ref}}
$$

There's probably an easier way to get this, but the above works from first principles.

You can co-scale R1,R2 and R3,R4 as desired. Since 3k and 8k are not E24 resistors, using (e.g.) 75k and 200k will still be exact but will be more accessible.

Comment: Spot on! I really could not get around these values, even though tackled the task the way you described- thank you. This solution is nice especially since you have resistor values that are overlapping (less types in the circuit) and are available.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło What do you mean by get-around? If this is not intuitive I can supply the solution procedure. I've also edited the answer to show resistor values that are more common.

Comment: Thanks for the value. Maybe you could show how to get to the shown 2 equations from base?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Sure; edited

Comment: Thank you What is V_off in your ewuations?

Comment: `V_off` = 0.768

Answer (score 4):

OK. Here is what I have.

You can test this with the simulate link to the lower left of the schematic.

The math is as follows. To get 0.768V from a 2.048V reference, you need a voltage divider with resistances in the ratio of 5:3. You used a 56K resister in your attempt, so I did the same. That gave me a 33.6K for the grounded leg of the voltage divider. Using Thevenin's theorem, the voltage divider is equivalent to a 0.768V source with a 21K resistor in series. To make the op amp have an amplification of 1, the remaining resistors should be 21K.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feDMLt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: For the right choice of values, R1 is not needed.

Comment: Your circuit does the same functionality as @Reinderien, but is more complex. Thank you for the right answer!

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how set you are on getting absolutely full-range out of your ADC, you can get quite close with just a couple of diodes. The don't start conducting until around 0.65 volts forward, and you get a ~ 0.65 V drop, so just putting two diodes in series:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa0v7w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Gets you a result on this order (looking at a 3V sine wave as the input):

[image]

If you really need to ensure you maintain *precisely* the values you gave, this won't work--but for a lot of purposes, its entirely adequate, and obviously a *lot* simpler/cheaper than anything using an op-amp.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The solution is quite smart, but unfortunately for my needs its too inaccurate.